# Make the datatype of one column a type of another column?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server

```
ALTER TABLE Students
AlTER COLUMN Name nickname
```

I want to ALTER Name column datatype to be as that of the nickname column datatype but an error occurred like:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
>   Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type nickname.

Following the example from `w3schools` on SQL tutorial, there was an example that talked about changing the datatype of one column using another, I tried it on SQL Server Management Studio but it didn't work.

Comment: Add a link to that example.

Comment: Do you know what the data type is for column `[nickname]`? It may just be easier to execute an `ALTER COLUMN` statement with the new data type (e.g. `ALTER TABLE Students ALTER COLUMN [Name] NVARCHAR(50)`)

Comment: No, this is not possible without adding complexity of user-defined datatypes. Your tutorial is either incorrect or is based on a different variation of SQL.